# A professor uses a machine to write novels that copy the style of great dead writers

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to find a short story about a machine that writes novels of dead great writers.  The main character is a professor and finds he can use the machine to pretend he wrote great  novels in the perfect styles of deceased famous writers.

Comment: We need more data. When and where did you read it, in which language, are there more characters, how does it end?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: When I read the title, I thought _The Monkey's Finger_, but that's not it.

Comment: you sure it was fiction? http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20150122-could-a-robot-write-a-novel  ;)

Comment: The story takes place in a college town and highlights the initial delight of the protagonist and the eventual feelings of guilt.

Answer (score 5):

### Possibly "[The Great Automatic Grammatizator](https://www.roalddahlfans.com/dahls-work/short-stories/the-great-automatic-grammatizator/)" by Roald Dahl.

> Adoph Knipe is a computer genius but has always longed to be a writer. He convinces his boss, Mr. Bohlen, to let him build a computer that will write stories. Knipe succeeds and sets up a publishing company as a front for this new mass-produced literature. Later they modify the machine to write novels and begin making thousands of dollars. The final step in their domination of the publishing industry is to buy out real authors and pay them to never write again. The surprise in the story comes at the end, when the narrator reveals that “over half of all the novels and stories published in the English language” are now created by Adolph Knipe on the Great Automatic Grammatizator. The conclusion of the story is written in first-person, as a struggling writer listens to his nine hungry children cry and tries to resist the lure of Knipe’s “golden contract.” “Give us strength, Oh Lord,” he prays for all true artists, “to let our children starve.”

The only difference is that this story involved copying the styles of *living* authors, not dead ones.